# Razor page set inputs value on button click

Tags: asp.net, input, setvalue

I want to click a button on a razor page that set values for two input fields "on the client side".

I have two input fields

```
<input id="pageBatteryName" name="pageBatteryName" asp-for="Firmware.BatteryName" class="form-control"  />
<select id="pageDeviceId" name="pageDeviceId" asp-for="Firmware.DeviceId" class ="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.DeviceId"></select>
```

A button

```
<input type="button" onClick="AutoFill()" value="Auto Fill"/>
```

and a javascript

```
@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}

<script type="text/javascript">
    function AutoFill()
    {
        var vBatteryName = document.getElementsByName('pageBatteryName');
        vBatteryName.value = "QWERTY1234";
        var vDeviceId = document.getElementsByName('pageDeviceId');
        vDeviceId.value = 2;
        vBatteryName.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
        vDeviceId.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));

    }
</script>
}
```

The code above do not work. I spend a day trying to do that. Could You help me please?

If the button works I will set the inputs based on selected input file name (nearly all of input fields for my form).
I used OnPostAutoFill post c# method but it reloads a page and I found that javascript can be usefull here. If javascript is not suitable for this task, can you show me the way?

Answer (score 1):

`getElementsByName` returns an array of elements. Instead, you can use `getElementById` to get a single element:

```
var vBatteryName = document.getElementById('pageBatteryName');
vBatteryName.value = "QWERTY1234";
```

This works for an input field.

For a select, you want to add option elements to the select like this:

```
var opt = document.createElement('option');
opt.value = 0;
opt.innerHTML = 1;
vDeviceId.appendChild(opt);
```

See this jsfiddle to see your code in action: https://jsfiddle.net/12xndyLo/

Comment: Thank you. You fixed my fault but the html Events does not always works onChange="AutoFill()" and it's much better to use EventListener to handle events:
var pageHexFile = document.getElementById("pageHexFile");
pageHexFile.addEventListener("change", function() { AutoFill(); });